# Donor with only email address shows no display name

Tags: civicontribute, search-results

If a NEW donor makes a donation and only supplies their email address*, the displayed name is blank in WordPress civi 4.6.4 and above. (*This can happen when someone donates directly through PayPal, civi only retains the email, or sometimes in a "pay later" situation when only an email is required.)

In my old civi (4.2.7, yes I know very old) it always defaulted to the email address if no name was supplied. Now that I'm upgraded to 4.6.4 the email address does not show in the contribution dashboard, contribution searches or the soft credit section on the donation tab for a contact.

I tested in the Demo site. If a donor already exists with just a email, then it's peachy it shows the email name. But if you make a new donation with a new email address there's no displayed name. (See below). You can go into the contact, press 'add or edit email' and then immediately press save and civi will then start displaying the email properly.

Any idea why it won't do this to begin with?[image]

EDIT: Reported as [CRM-16936](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16936)

Comment: Looks like this fix has been merged and will be in the next CiviCRM release: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6365/

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bug in recent CiviCRM, especially given that you've confirmed the behavior change on demo site.

Why this happened isn't so important I expect as what to do to get it fixed, and whether this change in behavior is intended - I'd guess not.

To get it fixed, the next step would be to open an issue in the bug tracker at http://issues.CiviCRM.org - your details here are perfect for that.

You or your organization could contribute further towards the fix, but a thorough bug report like you've provided is a great contribution already.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting/explaining the bug tracker. I've always shied away from it in the past in the case I was using it incorrectly. Issue is posted now!

Comment: This is also true for sites using Drupal as a CMS. I thought it was a 'WAD' but maybe not.